# how to understand xy - XY (Where x, y are random variables and XY are their means)

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, means

[Part where I don't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeDHH.png)

Hey guys,

I'm just looking at this paper called: ON THE EXACT VARIANCE OF PRODUCTS.
[http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~cga/var/2281592.pdf](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ecga/var/2281592.pdf)

I'm a bit confused in the second section :
2.THE CASE WHERE THE RANDOM VARIABLES ARE INDEPENDENT

Where it says:

```
Since xy - XY = XY[(dx + l)(dy + 1) - 1] = XY[dy + dx + dxdy](1)
where dx = (x - X)/X and dy = (y - Y)/ Y
```

x,y here are both random variables, and X,Y are E(x) and E(y), their respective means.

How does one get to the equation in (1), and why the  choice for dx and dy here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: At first read, it looks like there is a misprint.  Just writing everything out, we see that $xy-XY=XY[(dx+1)(dy+1)-1)$ without the second term.  Indeed, the right hand here is equal to $XY[dx+dy+dxdy]$.  So I think that second "$-$" should be "$=$".

Comment: Hi yeah that is my mistake,

Comment: Please refer to the original text: (part screenshot) https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeDHH.png

Comment: Right, so then the two equalities are a matter of routine algebra.  Nothing to do with independence (though I suppose that will be used elsewhere).  What's the confusion?

Comment: Thanks for the help. The confusion is the equality between xy - XY = XY[ (dx+1)(dy+1) -1 ] 
Does XY[ things in the bracket] mean multiply XY to whatever is in the bracket?

Comment: Yes, it does.  Just  write out all the terms.  I suppose you are meant to assume that $XY\neq 0$ but that doesn't really alter the computation.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. 
I do see that The second and third terms are indeed equal.
But how does xy - XY = XY[(dx + l)(dy + 1) - 1]
How can we even interpret xy - XY? 
Thanks again.

Comment: Just multiply it out.  $dx+1=\frac xX$ and $dy+1=\frac yY$ so $(dx+1)(dy+1)-1=\frac {xy}{XY}-1=\frac {xy-XY}{XY}$.  And now multiplying by $XY$ clears the denominator.

Comment: ahh. Thanks a lot!!!